# How do you troubleshoot JSDOM's ResourceLoader?

Tags: javascript, jsdom

I'm loading this html in [JSDOM](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom):

#### ./template.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>hi</div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log(`2nd script: Does window.$ exist?`, window.$ !== undefined && window.$ !== null);
        console.log(`2nd script: Does $ exist?`, $ !== undefined && $ !== null);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My question is, how do I know if a resource (e.g., `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js`) was successfully loaded? That url is simply an example. I'm asking in general.

Here is the rest of my project structure:

#### Project Structure

```
.
├── .eslintrc.json
├── .prettierrc
├── index.js
├── package.json
└── template.html
```

#### ./index.js

```
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import { JSDOM, ResourceLoader } from 'jsdom';

class CustomResourceLoader extends ResourceLoader {
  fetch(url, options) {
    console.log(`Called with ${url}`);

    return super.fetch(url, options); // was the resource loaded correctly?
  }
}

const dom = await JSDOM.fromFile(`./template.html`, {
  url: 'http://localhost',
  runScripts: 'dangerously',
  resources: new CustomResourceLoader(),
  pretendToBeVisual: true,
});

const window = dom.window;

const $1 = window.eval('window.$');
console.log(
  `jsdom module: Does window.$ exist?`,
  $1 !== undefined && $1 !== null
);
```

#### ./package.json

```
{
  "name": "jsdom-sandbox",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A simple sandbox for playing around with jsdom.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run exec && jasmine",
    "exec": "node index.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^5.1.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.25",
    "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.4",
    "eslint": "^8.52.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prettier/sync": "^0.3.0",
    "jsdom": "^22.1.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.3"
  }
}
```